# In unit test, real code is run instead of function stub & mocked object

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-s3, mockito

It is a very simple unit test case.

I have two methods in class `School`:

```
protected S3Object getAwsObject(AmazonS3Client client, String bucketName, String keyName) {
        GetObjectRequest objRequest =  new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName);
        return client.getObject(objRequest);
}
```

Above method is invoked by the 2nd method showing below:

```
public void doTask() {
   // get client
   AmazonS3Client client = getAwsS3Client();
   // invoke the 1st method
   S3Object s3Obj = getAwsObject(client, "my-bucket", "my-key");
   ...
}
```

I use [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to test the method `doTask()`, I tried to **mock** the `AmazonS3Client` & **stub** function `getAwsObject()` :

```
@Test
public void testDoTask() {
   // partially mocked School instance
   School school = new School();
   School schoolSpy = Mockito.spy(school);
   // mock the client & s3 object
   AmazonS3Client mockedClient = Mockito.mock(AmazonS3Client.class);

   S3Object mockedS3Obj = Mockito.mock(S3Object.class);

   Mockito.doReturn(mockedClient)
       .when(schoolSpy).getAwsS3Client();

   // PROBLEM HERE: I stub function to return mocked S3Object, but real code is run
   Mockito.doReturn(mockedS3Obj)
          .when(schoolSpy).getAwsObject(mockedClient, "my-bucket", "my-key");

   // system under test
   schoolSpy.doTask();
}
```

When run the test, I got the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. 

(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: 6B973FC095C28524),...
```

Looks like the test case run the real code `client.getObject(objRequest)` instead of using the stub of `getAwsObject(...)` , WHY?

Comment: How are you injecting the mock into your object?  Rather, how would you think that it could be done inside of a method that takes no arguments and news up an instance of `AmazonS3Client`?

Comment: As you see in my code, I use Mockito.doReturn(mockedObject).when(schoolSpy).any_school_function()  to return mocked object when function is called.

Comment: Yes, I see you *using* the mock in your test, but I don't see how you're actually injecting the mock into the class you want to test.

Comment: news up an instance of AmazonS3Client ??  As you see in my code, `getAwsS3Client()` returns the client, and I use `Mockito.doReturn(mockedClient).when(schoolSpy).getAwsS3Client()` to force the function to return a mocked S3 client. What is wrong with that?

Comment: I maintain that from what we're seeing, we can't prove that those mocks are being injected.

Comment: I see `S3Object` and `AmazonS3Client` are classes. Not interfaces. I suppose Mockito calls default constructors of them while call `mock` method. Try to use interfaces instead of classes. E.g. `AmazonS3` instead of `AmazonS3Client` and `Serializable` instead of `S3Object`

Comment: This could happen if the first method doesn't run properly.  Mockito is looking for a call to the second method who's first argument matches `mockedClient`, so if it doesn't match, it won't mock the method.  Can you post the code for `getAwsS3Client()`?

Comment: I just tried replicating your example. Using `mockito core 1.10.19` everything works as expected. (`getAwsObject()` is called with a mocked client, and a mock object is returned.

Comment: As @Martinhansen already commented (I should have read all comments before posting an answer (which I now have deleted)) I was not able to reproduce this issue with Mockito 1.10.19 either. What version are you using? Is your `getAwsS3Client` method somehow static or not compatible with Mockito? You might also try to use `Mockito.doReturn(mockedS3Obj)
        .when(schoolSpy).getAwsObject(any(AmazonS3Client.class), anyString(), anyString());` instead, which should catch all cases in case the client object is somehow flawed (which method signature we don't know)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't succeed in making your mocking work, you can solve your problem by overriding the original methods this way:

```
// mock the client & s3 object
final AmazonS3Client mockedClient = Mockito.mock(AmazonS3Client.class);
final S3Object mockedS3Obj = Mockito.mock(S3Object.class);

School school = new School(){

  @Override
  protected S3Object getAwsObject(AmazonS3Client client, String bucketName, String keyName) {
    return mockedS3Obj;
  }

  @Override
  protected AmazonS3Client getAwsS3Client() {
    return mockedClient;
  }

};

// system under test
school.doTask();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not use spy but in legacy code. (http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy%28T%29). If you delegate the creation of objects in not static factories/builders it will be easy to test.

But, in this case, if mockito executes the real code, then your doReturn... is not valid. I think that Mockito does not validate the params clause and then it not launchs the doReturn clause.

You have

```
doReturn...getAwsObject(mockedClient, "my-bucket", "my-key")
```

If you do the next and it works then i am right 100%

```
doReturn...getAwsObject(any(AmazonS3Client.class), anyString(), anyString())
```

I had problems when i used mock params and not-mock params in the same statement. try this:

```
getAwsObject(mockedClient, eq("my-bucket"), eq("my-key"));
```

If this does not work try with another solution like:

```
eq(mockedClient), eq(...), eq(...)
```

Finally, if it does not work, maybe @max solution will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple wrong things are done here.

Spy should not be created for the Class under test.

Unit test are written for whole class to test behaviours in the class. If the methods in the same class are Mocked, then whats the purpose of unit tests?

Only dependent classes should be mocked and possible provide setter methods to set these dependencies. This way it can be decided whether to inject real objects or mocked objects.